How to render the data label over axis element of an excel chart?


Hello, I have a chart formatting problem which I cannot find a setting or solution for yet.
The issue is that the chart axis is rendered on a layer above the data label. I want to show the data label on the Y axis and have it's text box cover up what's beneath it. What occurs now is that the numbers from the axis are showing through the text box of the data label and sometimes making the data label unreadable if they overlap enough. The same problem occurs if I use data callout boxes instead and I cannot find a setting to bring the data label to the top layer or send the axis to the back.
